# Bubbling up in the AWT event model?

Tags: java, events, swing, awt

If I implement an action event on a `JFrame` that has some buttons it give me
the button clicked via `getSource` but if I implement on the same frame a mouse event
it doesn't rise me the event for the buttons but only for that `JFrame`.

Why?

The event bubbling seems to work only for action event so what model Swing implements?

Which listeners types works in a bubbling way?

Comment: I you add an ActionListener or a MouseListener to the button, then the source of the event will be the button. If you are getting different results then post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem, because the problem is with your code and we can't guess what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: Cross-posted to http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/browse_frm/thread/8cd7b17672d24caa

Answer (score 2):

Event bubbling up in AWT only works for mouse events, and then only if there are no mouse listeners on the child component.

This can be quite confusing if you have, say, a `JComboBox` which is typically implemented by the PL&F with a text field and a button component. You might want to look up "glass panes".

I suggest ignoring containment hierarchy as much as possible. Also create listeners that know their context and dot use `getSource`. And don't extend classes (such as `JFrame`, `JPanel` and `Thread`) unnecessarily.

Comment: @xdevel2000 `JFrame` does not have `addActionListener`.